# How do i add sprite images in my pdf using iText?

Tags: java, itext

In my case i created a pdf file using iText in java and im trying to use sprite images in my pdf file.. Is there anyway that sprite images could be added to pdf using iText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but takes some effort.

What you need is an image and a path. The path should be a rectangle and is used to clip the image (so that you can see only the part of the sprite that you want to show).

Here is an example from iText in Action: [part3.chapter10.ClippingPath](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=191)